# How are "soeben" and "eben" different from one another?

Tags: difference, usage

I'd like to know what kind of difference there is between these two synonyms when they are used in the meaning "just now (happened)".

> **Soeben** schlägt es zwölf.
>
> **Eben** schlägt es zwölf.

And "**So eben** schlägt es zwölf" is incorrect, right?

And when "soeben" and "eben" are used in the meaning "just now (happened)", is it more normal to use the present tense verb "schlägt" rather than "hat geschlagen"?

Answer (score 6):

**Eben** can be used in different than a time bound context, while **soeben** always refers to a very recent moment. Here's an example:

> Q: Warum ist die Banane krumm?
>   A: Das ist **eben** so.<sup>1</sup>

In the above example replacing **eben** with **soeben** wouldn't make any sense.

Same for

> Das Gelände ist weitgehend **eben**.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>I well know that there are better answers for that particular question, but that's not the subject of the discussion here.</sub>

Comment: "eben" has several very different meanings, you show two of them. It could also mean the opposite of steep, but this is not the question.

Comment: @rexkogitans Yes, there are many different contexts where ***eben*** can be used ,and its not simply replacable with ***soeben***. Isn't that exactly what the question is about?

Comment: Regarding the foornote, the only culturally acceptable answer must be: *Weil keiner in den Urwald zog und die Banane gerade bog.* :-) For *eben so*, the difference to *so eben* is obviously very small; also note *ebenso*, "likewise", synonym with *gleichfalls*, and note that *gleich*, is also used in the temporal paradigm, with *sogleich* practically though not always strictly equivalent to *soeben*; The last example should be *ebenmäßig*, if only in analogy to *gleichmäßig*. Due to *gleich* < *ge* + *likaz* (whence also *Leiche*) cp. *eben* to *bone*, though I somewhat doubt \*likaz.

Comment: Die Frage stellt deutlich heraus, dass es um "eben" im Sinne von "just now" geht, nicht um die ebene Fläche oder "das ist eben so". Die Antwort hat das Thema verfehlt.

Answer (score 4):

"**Soeben** schlägt es zwölf." means it is right now happenig (still counting the strokes). "**Eben** hat es zwölf geschlagen." means it is now 12 o´clock and the bell became silent just a couple of seconds ago.

That's how I would use it.

Of course **eben** and **soeben** can be used with both tenses. But I would not use "**Eben** schlägt es zwölf." - even when grammatically correct, it sounds dated. In this case I would use "**Grade** schlägt es zwölf."

How much time has passed in the perfect-variant depends on the context.

And as already mentioned in other answers, **soeben** is only used in the timely manner. **Eben** can also be used for *smooth, even, plain* or in context **eben derselbe** = *selfsame*, **eben weil** = *precisely because*.

Comment: _Eben_ can be used in very different contexts than _soeben_ also. Maybe it's worth mentioning these.

Comment: This is confusing, because you are also using different tenses. You can also say "Soeben hat es zwölf geschlagen". Furthermore, "eben" can be used for a longer time span than just a couple seconds. I'd certainly say minutes, surely up to half an hour.

Comment: Eben! Eben noch war Obama US-Präsident, herrscht nun ein Rumpeldiplomat. Die Zeitspanne ist sehr abhängig vom Kontext. Fragen zu grundsätzlich anderen Bedeutungen von "eben" hat die Frage ausgeschlossen - mir leuchtet nicht ein, wieso man darauf beharrt das dennoch zu thematisieren.

Answer (score 2):

Zusammenfassend: **soeben** is only used to refer to events which happened just now or are happening now. 
Another important difference that goes beyond the temporal meaning, is that **eben** is often used with the meaning of the modal particle "halt", but with broader semantics and usage than that of "halt".

Comment: Die Bedeutung ist in der Frage ausdrücklich auf "just now" eingegrenzt.

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis. Habe die Antwort korrigiert. Finde es schon wichtig, dass das Wort "modal particle" erwähnt wurde, weil eben eben ein sehr wichtiger Bestandteil der deutschen Umgangssprache ist.

Answer (score -1):

Both sentences are highly colloquial, with limited distribution <sup>[where?]</sup>, if not incorrect, and mean whatever the speaker wants them to mean.

*soeben* is probably a conjunction equating two events, "at the same time". Whereas *eben'* should probably be *ebend*, in analogy to *anschließend*, which is adverbial and should not appear in front position, as *Es* already does that job very well, "Es schlägt Zwölf*. Compare *Hier kommt Kurt*: *Eben schlägt Zwölf*--one of these is wrong, but why? *ebe-n* is mainly an adjective, cp. *grü-n*, *erhabe-n*, etc.

Where *eben* is used you can also use *jetzt*,  for the present, or *gerade* for the near past and *eben gerade*. Near past might in some dialects actually even just use present tense with a temporal key word, I'm actually even just not sure.

Comment: I would not call the example sentences colloquial, on the contrary. But I _would_ call "ebend" highly colloquial, if not plainly wrong. "Ebend" is a malapropism of "eben", "ebenda", "ebendrum", etc.

Comment: @SirJane there is simply little to no use for a situational adverb of time in formal writing, simply because it is imprecise. And it is surely used in conversation as a discurse marker when introducing a new topic. Instances of "kannst du das *mal eben[d]* halten* are highly informal at that, and no, *mal* has nothing to do with that, it just goes to prove the point. Whether *ebend* seems unusual to you has no weight, as I was trying to make a formal argumen

Comment: I do maybe misuse *colloquial* and confuse it with *informal*. The example sentences are weird anyhow, I am generalizing.